# Find largest integer in table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**The Challenge:**

I need to find the most popular discussion in a forum.

**Background Information:**

- forum has many discussions
- discussion belongs to forum
- discussion has an attribute called `views` which stores how many
  times a user has viewed a discussion.
- using a postgres database.

**My Solution:**

Create an instance method in the `Forum` model that loops through every single discussion and sees how many view each one has:

```
def most_popular_discussion 
    record_view = 0

    self.discussions.each do |d|
        record_views = d.views if d.views > record_views 
    end

    record_views
end
```

**Why I've Made A Question:**

My solution appears to be disastrously inefficient as it queries the discussion table for **every single entry.** This method will get slower and slower as the database gets bigger and bigger. I wouldn't mind *too* much, but the `most_popular_discourse` method is also going to be requested a lot (on every user's profile page), and will really slow things up.

So how should I find the largest integer in a table? **or (and I think this is probably the better way)** should I actually save the record number of views, rather than working it out every time?

Maybe have another table called `statistics` for my application to use, with just two columns, `name:string` and `information:string` and use it store miscellaneous statistics?

Then, every-time someone views a discussion, I'd do *something* like this:

```
def iterate_views(ip)
    current_views = self.views + 1 

    self.views = current_views        

    record_views_statistic = Statistic.find_by(name: 'record_views')
    record_views_statistic.update_attributes(information: current_views.to_s) if current_views > record_views_statistic.information 

    # I convert current_views to a string before saving because the statistics table's `information` column holds strings in order to keep the table open and miscellaneous. 
end
```

what do you think about that approach? Both interact with the database a fair bit, but this second approach wouldn't slow down proportionally to the amount of data in the database.

Comment: You should do this in SQL

Comment: Do something like this .. Discussion.maximum("record_view") ..
This will give you the maximum value in the record_view column

Answer (score 1):

This approach will give you the most popular discussion, and is much simpler than your two solutions.

```
def most_popular_discussion
  self.discussions.order(views: :desc).first
end
```

To get the highest number of views, you could either use `most_popular_discussion.views` or use a function like:

```
def record_views
  self.discussions.maximum(:views)
end
```

Note that I've included ways to find both the most viewed discussion and the highest number of views, because your challenge says you'd like to find the most popular discussion but both of your solutions just seem to find the record number of views among a forum's discussions.

As for your solutions, your second one seems to be closer to a good solution, but why not just cache the most popular discussion's `views` count in the `Forum` model? Say we add a `record_views` column to the `forums` table.

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum

  def iterate_views
    self.views += 1
    if self.forum.present? && self.views > self.forum.record_views
      self.forum.record_views = self.views 
    end
  end
end
```

Then, to find the most popular discussion in the `Forum` model (assuming ties don't matter):

```
def most_popular_discussion
  self.discussions.where(views: self.record_views).first
end
```